# Discrete Binary Search Main Theory

Tags: binary-search

I have read this: https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/binary-search.
I can't understand some parts==>

> What we can call the main theorem states that binary search can be
>   used if and only if for all x in S, p(x) implies p(y) for all y > x.
>   This property is what we use when we discard the second half of the
>   search space. It is equivalent to saying that ¬p(x) implies ¬p(y) for
>   all y < x (the symbol ¬ denotes the logical not operator), which is
>   what we use when we discard the first half of the search space.

But I think this condition does not hold when we want to find an element(checking for equality only) in an array and this condition only holds when we're trying to find Inequality for example when we're searching for an element greater or equal to our target value.

Example: We are finding 5 in this array.

```
indexes=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
        1 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

we define p(x)=>

```
 if(a[x]==5) return true else return false
```

step one=>middle index = 8+1/2 = 9/2 = 4 ==> a[4]=5
          and p(x) is correct for this and from the main theory, the result is that 
          p(x+1) ........ p(n) is true but its not.

So what is the problem?

Comment: Well they did say `which is what we use when we discard the first half of the search space.` and you said `this condition does not hold when we want to find an element`. It's like going around in circles. ? There are 2 more conditions in binary search, they must be talking about them.

Comment: The "theorem" states that you can't use binary search with that predicate in that array.

Comment: @molbdniloI cant undrestand please explain more.

Comment: @AiraBanazadeh The theorem states the requirement on the array and the predicate for binary search to be possible. (Informally, it does not say "if you search, the array has this property", it says "if the array has this property, you can search it".) Your array and predicate do not fulfill those requirements (`p(5)` is true, but `p(6)` is false) so you can't use them for binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We CAN use that theorem when looking for an exact value, because we
only use it when **discarding** one half. If we are looking for say 5,
and we find say 6 in the middle, the we can discard the upper half,
because we now know (due to the theorem) that all items in there are > 5

Also notice, that if we have a sorted sequence, and want to find any element
that satisfies an inequality, looking at the end elements is enough.

Comment: But I think we can use binary search in other situations
For example, we can use it when we want to get the first element in our sorted array that is bigger or equal to an exact value.  ( >= property)

Comment: @AiraBanazadeh Binary search will find *one* element with the desired property if any exist, not necessarily the first. For instance, looking for `>= 1` in `{1,2,3,4,5}` will find `3`.